# Conectar Login con base de datos JAVA - MySql

Tags: java, mysql, login

Hola a todos soy un poco nuevo en esto de la programación y últimamente he estado intentando crear  un login sencillo con Java y MySql. Ya he creado mi conexión sin problemas y las bases de datos pero no consigo unir todo en mi main. Soy nuevo y aun no conozco muchas cosas. Agradecería su ayuda.  Muchas gracias.

```
package Modelo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Scanner;
        
public class MetodosSQL {
    
    
    public static conexionDB conectar = new conexionDB();
    public static PreparedStatement sentencia_preparada;
    public static ResultSet resultado;
    public static String sql;
    public static int resultado_numero = 0;
    
    public static String BuscarUsuarioRegistrado (String usuario, String contraseña){
        String busqueda_usuario = null ;
        Connection conexion=null;
        
        try {
            conexion = conexionDB.conectar();
            String sentencia_buscar_usuario = ("SELECT user_Admin, Password_Admin FROM administradores WHERE user_Admin='"+usuario+"' && Password_Admin='"+ contraseña +"'");
            sentencia_preparada = conexion.prepareStatement(sentencia_buscar_usuario);
            resultado = sentencia_preparada.executeQuery();
            if(resultado.next()){
                busqueda_usuario = "Usuario Login Exitoso";
                
            }else {
                busqueda_usuario = "Usuario no encontrado";
            } 
            
            conexion.close();
            
        } catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        
        }
        return busqueda_usuario;
    } 
 }
```

```
package Modelo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] ar) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         String user;
         String password;

         System.out.println("Log in:");
         System.out.println("username: ");
         user = input.next();

         System.out.println("password: ");
         password = input.next();
        
         
        
      
      }
    
}
```

Basicamente lo que requiero es que al ingresar un usuario y una contraseña por teclado me arroje un mensaje que diga que el login fue realizado.

Comment: Si creaste bien tu clase ConexionDB. Simplemente en el main, una vez escrito el ``user`` y el ``password`` con el Scanner, llama a ``MetodosSQL.BuscarUsuarioRegistrado(user, password)``, esto te devuelve el String por si luego lo vas a imprimir.

Comment: Lo puse asi y no pasa nada  ```System.out.println("password: ");
         password = input.next();
        
         
         MetodosSQL clase = new MetodosSQL ();
         clase.BuscarUsuarioRegistrado(user, password);
      
      }```

Comment: No crees un objeto de MetodoSQL, el método que estas usando es estático a menos que lo quites, lo puedes llamar directamente, y tienes que imprimir el String que te devuelve ese método ``System.out.println(MetodosSQL.BuscarUsuarioRegistrado(user, password))``

Comment: Lo intentare, gracias.

Comment: Sólo un consejo, USA [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), son más rápidos y son MUCHO MÁS SEGUROS, pues evitan inyecciones SQL

Answer (score 1):

No hace lo que deseas porque no estas llamando a la **clase** `MetodosSQL` y tampoco estas **setteando** parámetros en `BuscarUsuarioRegistrado`.

Debajo de tu línea
`password = input.next();`
Pon el siguiente fragmento de codigo:
`MetodosSQL.BuscarUsuarioRegistrado(user, password);`

Como recomendación te diría que empieces a trabajar con modelo 3 capas.

saludos.

Comment: También tiene que imprimir la variable que le devuelve el método por la consola.

Comment: Puedes asignarle una variable por ejemplo:
`String repuestaSQL = "";
respuestaSQL = MetodosSQL.BuscarUsuarioRegistrado(user, password);`

e imprimirla de dos formas:

1. Directamente de la clase:
`System.out.println(MetodosSQL.BuscarUsuarioRegistrado(user, password));`

2. Con la variable respuestaSQL
`System.out.println(respuesSQL);`